# How can I make logical AND in intellij idea search

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes I would find very useful to search (ctrl - shift - f) in intellij idea all files containing "string1" AND "string2".

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for `string1`, then for `string2` while using scope `Files in Previous Search Result`
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex search. Here's an example:

[image]

This regex: `(?s)^(?=.*?string1)(?=.*?string2)` matches any file that contains both strings, it doesn't care about order (i.e. which string comes first in a given file) nor does it care about the number of strings you search for so you can add additional criteria by appending another `(?=.*?_your_text_here)`.

In addition, it can be easily extended to cover logical ORs ...

```
(?s)^(?=.*?string1)|(?=.*?string2)
```